# How to create object from its Type.GUID

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, factory

I have a set of classes that inherit from the same base class and I need to create a factory method for instantiation of the different base class implementations based on the GuidAttribute attached to the implementing class. So basically the scenario is like this:

```
abstract class Foo
{
   /* ... */
   public static Foo Create(Guid guid) {
      Type type;
      // Resolve the type ?
      return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Foo;
   }
}

[Guid("<guid1>")]
class Bar : Foo { ... }

[Guid("<guid2>")]
class Baz : Foo { ... }
```

Is there any other way than iterating all the types in the loaded assemblies and caching the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be automatic but you could simply build a `Dictionary<Guid,Type>` or if there's a common interface/class in each assembly (ala plugin architecture) request it register the types accordingly.

There's no need to use reflection for everything :)  I find it less elegant in many cases.

Comment: Your answer brought me to a nice idea.. I could create the dictionary registration code with a T4 template :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is another way. Certainly, that is how I would do it.